# How to improve Named Entity Recognition in edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am investigating NLP processing of large texts with `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP`.

with the following properties my results contain all required PERSON names, however there are a large amount of "*mistakes*".

```
        val props = Properties()
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions,regexner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote")
        props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural")

        consumeBook("book.txt", StanfordCoreNLP(props))
```

Where consume book resembles:-

```
private fun consumeBook(fileName: String, pipeline: StanfordCoreNLP) = File(fileName).forEachLine { currentLine ->

    val data = currentLine.trimIndent()

    if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
        val document = CoreDocument(data)

        pipeline.annotate(document)

        document.sentences().forEach { sentence ->
            sentence.entityMentions().filter { it.entityType() == "PERSON" }.forEach { entityMention ->
                characters.add(entityMention.text())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `characters` is declared as follows:-

```
private val characters: MutableSet<String> = TreeSet()
```

My set of `characters` does contain all the full names of the books characters, however it also contains `LOCATION`s & `CITY`s from the book along with values such as these

```
he
her
hers
him
his
she
```

is there additional configuration i can add/refactor to improve the quality of the PERSON Named Entity Recognition?

from my investigation so far IMHO Standford NLP library is much better than Apache OpenNLP.

The version of Stanford NLP I am using is:-

```
implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:4.4.0'
implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:4.4.0:models'
```